# Identify event that triggered the function

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

How can I get the event that triggered a function using jQuery?

```
$(document).on("click touchstart", "#element", function() {
  if( EVENT IS TOUCHSTART ) {
     // DO THIS SINCE EVENT WAS TOUCHSTART
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is **[`type`](https://api.jquery.com/event.type/)** property for events

```
$(document).on("click touchstart", "#element", function(event) {
  if(event.type == "touchstart") {
     // DO THIS SINCE EVENT WAS TOUCHSTART
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Also you can specify [event and handler as object](http://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data) in **[`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data)** method

```
$(document).on({
  "touchstart": function() {
    // DO THIS SINCE EVENT WAS TOUCHSTART
  },
  "click": function() {
    // DO THIS SINCE EVENT WAS CLICK
  }
}, "#element");
```